# Google Analytics Java API Filter Update error

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I'm working on using the Google Analytics Management API for Filter Update. I have been trying to use this [method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/analytics/Analytics.Management.Filters.Update.html) to update my filter, but apparently it does not work.

Below is a snippet of my update code:

```
private static void updateFilter(Analytics analytics, String accountID) {

    FilterExpression details = new FilterExpression();
    details.setField("GEO_DOMAIN");
    details.setMatchType("EQUAL");
    details.setExpressionValue(".example.com");
    details.setCaseSensitive(false);

    // Construct the body of the request.
    Filter body = new Filter();
    body.setName("My Domain Filter");
    body.setType("EXCLUDE");
    body.setExcludeDetails(details);

    try {
        analytics.management().filters().update("<valid GA ID>", "<valid filter ID>", body).execute();
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
        System.err.println("There was a service error: "
                + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error code I'm getting is 400 : Field id is required. To my knowledge, everything that is required of a filter has been initialized in the method. I do not know what "Field id is required" is supposed to mean.

Thanks for any help rendered.

Comment: JavaClent lib can be found here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ You code looks different from the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/update

Comment: @DaImTo "AnalyticsManagementFiltersFilterExpression" is an invalid expression and my IDE shows that it does not exist. I do not know why the code on that page is wrong. Also, I've tried the API Explorer demo on that page and it also gives me the same "Field id is required" error.

Comment: @DaImTo I don't quite understand what you mean by management write beta. Currently, I am able to create filters on the GA account via the create method, if that was what you were referring to.

Comment: Yeah never mind guess its not filters. Did you try patch.  I know that update requires you send all the fields. Its best to do a get on the filter then make your changes to it then update it.  (Sorry I am not a java expert) but I have done this with C#

Comment: @DaImTo GOOD LORD thanks for the help. I am pretty sure from my code I've settled everything there needs to be present for an EXCLUDE filter, but it just won't work. But yes patch worked perfectly fine, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant help to much with the Java.   I have done this before with C#.

When using Update everthing is updated. So it is best to do a get on the filter which returns a Filter body change that then use that as the [update](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/update).

But it is even easer if you are only changing a few things to use [Patch](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/filters/patch). Patch will update only what you send it instead of updating everything.

Comment: I checked out the Github repo, but sadly there wasn't anything like "google-api-java-client". My Java API client is from [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Downloads?tm=2). I pasted "Google_Service_Analytics_FilterExpression()" but apparently this method does not exist in the Java library. @DalmTo